# unable to mount lvm ext4 filesystem

Tags: ext4, lvm

I was moving a couple of physical volumes from my lvm. I managed to successfully pvmove and pvremove them. After this i was moving some files from the lvm to one of the removed pvs. Now during this my system hang up and i had to reboot. But once i rebooted i find that the superblock is corrupted on the lvm. Here is the actual error message:

```
bad geometry: block count 35651584 exceeds size of device (19922944 blocks)
```

e2fsck fails with message:

```
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 35651584 blocks
The physical size of the device is 19922944 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort<y>? yes
```

I tried e2fsck -b 8193 and that failed too.
What is going on? Is there anyway i can recover the data or is it lost?

EDIT:
  Oh, i have already done vgcfgrestore. it doesn't help.
EDIT1: 
 Trying to open the device from debugfs gives the error message

```
/dev/home/lvol0: Can't read an inode bitmap while reading inode bitmap
```

EDIT2:
    Adding a blog post link.http://anandjeyahar.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/lvm/

Comment: Really it was a failing hard disk... and the problem kept creeping up randomly... ran smard tools and then replaced the hard disk..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). You can get it pre-installed with several live rescue cds, or install it from the repo while running a normal live-cd.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below url, hope this will help you

http://www.digitalinux.com/2010/11/lvm-logical-volume-manager.html

Comment: Please explain how that helps, I only see a huge list of commands.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.